# Create Table using Enterprise Library

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

I have a method through which i am creating a Table in DB as shown below,

```
public void CreateTable(List<string> columnNames, string tableName)
{
  string connectionString = Utility.ReadDataFromConfig("ConnectionTest");

  using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
  {
    var server = new Server(new ServerConnection(connection));
    var db = server.Databases["GlassLookUp"];
    var newTable = new Table(db, tableName);
    var idColumn = new Column(newTable, "ID") { DataType = DataType.Int, Nullable = false };
    newTable.Columns.Add(idColumn);
    foreach (var titleColumn in from temp in columnNames
                  where temp != string.Empty
                  select new Column(newTable, temp) { DataType = DataType.VarChar(500), Nullable = true })
    {
      newTable.Columns.Add(titleColumn);
    }
    newTable.Create();
  }
}
```

I wanted the above method to be changed, so that Enterprise library is use. I have already used Enterprise library to execute stored procedures, but i dont know how to use Enterprise library to Create a Table.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your code is using [SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx).  I don't think you can use SMO in a useful way with Enterprise Library Data Access Application Block.  The best that you could do would be to get the connection:

```
public void CreateTable(List<string> columnNames, string tableName)
{
    Database database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("ConnectionTest");
    string connectionString = database.ConnectionString;

    //...
    newTable.Create();
}
```

But that is not adding very much value.  :)